# Different record count values in one query

Tags: sql, oracle10g

My goal is to achieve a result set like the following

```
CODE | TOTAL1 | TOTAL2  
1    | 56     | 34  
2    | 12     | 15  
3    | 90     | 3
```

There are 2 tables e.g tableA and tableB
The counts are different by tableB.type

```
SELECT   code, COUNT (*) AS total1  
FROM tableA a
WHERE a.ID IN (select ID from tableB
    where type = 'XYZ')
GROUP BY code


SELECT   code, COUNT (*) AS total2  
FROM tableA a
WHERE a.ID IN (select ID from tableB
    where type = 'ABC')
GROUP BY code
```

I'd like to display the count for each code per type in the same query

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subqueries :

```
SELECT   code, (select COUNT (*) AS total1  
FROM tableA a1
WHERE a.ID IN (select ID from tableB
    where type = 'XYZ')
    and a1.code = tableA.code) as Total1,  
(select COUNT (*) AS total2  
FROM tableA a2
WHERE a.ID IN (select ID from tableB
    where type = 'ABC')
    and a2.code = tableA.code) as Total2)
from tableA
group by Code
```

Answer (score 3):

No subquery

```
SELECT a.code,
sum(decode(b.type,'ABC',1,0)) AS total1,sum(decode(b.type,'XYZ',1,0)) AS total2
FROM tableA a
join tableB b on a.ID = b.ID
GROUP BY a.code
```

Regards
K

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of many ways to skin it is to UNION the two in an in-line view and then select the sum of the counts, like this:

SELECT code, SUM(total1) total1, SUM(total2) total2 FROM
(
SELECT code, COUNT(*) total1, 0 total2
FROM tableA a
WHERE a.ID IN (select ID from tableB
    where type = 'XYZ')
GROUP BY code
UNION
SELECT code, 0, COUNT (*)
FROM tableA a
WHERE a.ID IN (select ID from tableB
    where type = 'ABC')
GROUP BY code
)
GROUP BY code;