# How to count on different values in the same query with Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I have a class with a status :

```
class A{
  String status
}
```

This status can have values 'start','end','inprogress'.

I would like get the number of 'start','end' and 'inprogress' in one query.

I see this post : [Different record count values in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789418/different-record-count-values-in-one-query) but It's only for Oracle.

Is it possible to do that in Grails/GORM ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `executeQuery`:

```
def counts = A.executeQuery(
    'select status, count(status) from A group by status')
```

This will return a List of Object[], e.g.

```
for (row in counts) {
    println "there are ${row[1]} with status '${row[0]}'"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like criteria queries take a look at this:
[stackoverflow->Using groupProperty and countDistinct in Grails Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720060/using-groupproperty-and-countdistinct-in-grails-criteria)